# Is this fire and forget approach correct?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've implemented [instagram api realtime updates](http://instagram.com/developer/realtime/). Basically they fire a POST request to a url I provide when there are new images added based on my subscription.

They said:

" you should acknowledge the POST within a 2 second timeout--if you need to do more processing of the received information, you can do so in an asynchronous task."

so I built something like:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("realtime")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> IndexPost()
    {
        var form = Request.Form;

        Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
        System.IO.StreamReader str = new System.IO.StreamReader(Request.InputStream);
        string sBuf = str.ReadToEnd();

        // deserialize this from json
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        var updates = serializer.Deserialize<IEnumerable<RealtimeUpdate>>(sBuf).ToList();

        ProcessNewTaggedImages(updates);
        return new ContentResult { Content = "Ok" };

    }
```

where `ProcessNewTaggedImages` is running async.

```
 public async void ProcessNewTaggedImages(List<RealtimeUpdate> updates)
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
               // query Instagram api for new images
            }
        }
```

so basically when Instagram POSTs to www.mysite.com/realtime it does not wait for `ProcessNewTaggedImages`.

I just wanted to make sure this approach is correct for fire and forget approach because under Task.Run I receive a warning saying:

> Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the await operator to the result of the call.

but I don't want await here because

1. the result of my processing does not matter for instagram call
2. timeout for POST is 2 seconds so I don't want to wait for this processing.

Can you confirm I am on the right track? 
Ps: POST is working fine and all works good just wanted to confirm I've not done any mystake because I am mostly beginner to this async approach in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need fire and forget functionality you don't need to add async keywords to your methods as your are not doing any awaits. So remove the async keywords from your code and the compiler will not complain about your code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might need to  [read though this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) first.

And I quote: *"If an async method doesn’t use an await operator to mark a suspension point, the method executes as a synchronous method does, despite the async modifier."*